# Getting an error in Socket.io wordle project

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, runtime-error

I was creating a multiplayer wordle and am getting this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "socket.io-client". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`
The code is running fine when i run the client locally but not when i host the client side on netlify or github.
The following is the server side code:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {origin: ["https://h4r5h-10.github.io/private-test/"],}
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var tempArr = [];
console.log(tempArr)
var index; var correctWord;
io.on('connection', socket => {
    // console.log(socket.id);
    socket.on("disconnect", ()=>{
      const ind2 = tempArr.findIndex((obj) => obj.p1 == socket.id || obj.p2 == socket.id);
      if(ind2 != -1){
        tempArr.splice(ind2,1);
      }
    })
    // io.emit("sendword", correctWord);
    socket.on("submitguess", (arr, room) =>{
        socket.to(room).emit("sendtiles", arr);
    })
    socket.on("join-room", room =>{
        const ind1 = tempArr.findIndex((obj)=> obj.room == room);
        const ind2 = tempArr.findIndex((obj)=> obj.p1 == socket.id);
        // const ind3 = tempArr.findIndex((obj)=> obj.p2 == socket.id);
        if(ind1 !== -1 && tempArr[ind1].p1 && tempArr[ind1].p2) {
            socket.emit("room-full")
            return
        }
        socket.join(room);
        var count = 0;
        if(ind1 == -1)
        {
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length);
            correctWord = dictionary[index];
            tempArr.push({room: room, p1: socket.id, p2: null, correctWord: correctWord});
            socket.emit("sendword", correctWord);
            count = 1;
        }
      else if(ind2 !== -1){
            count = 1;
        }
        else if(ind1 !== -1 && ind2 == -1){
            tempArr[ind1].p2 = socket.id;
            socket.emit("sendword", correctWord);
        }
        io.to(room).emit("waiting-room", count);
      console.log(tempArr);
    })
    socket.on("socket-win", (id, room) => {
        const ind2 = tempArr.findIndex((obj) => obj.p1 == id || obj.p2 == id);
        socket.to(room).emit("shut-down", ind2);
        tempArr.splice(ind2,1);
    })
    socket.on("socket-exhaust", (id, room) => {
        const ind2 = tempArr.findIndex((obj) => obj.p1 == id || obj.p2 == id);
        socket.to(room).emit("exhaust-out", ind2);
        tempArr.splice(ind2,1);
    })
})

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The following is client side code:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Wordle Multiplayer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="index.js" defer></script>
    <!-- <script  src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>   -->
    <script type="/module" src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.7.5/socket.io.esm.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="restart-container hide" data-restart-con>
      <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="btn" onclick="window.location.reload()">New Game</button>
        <a href="../../index.html"><button class="btn">Menu</button></a>
      <button class="btn close" onclick="closeRestart()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="join-container">
      <div class="join-btn-container">
        <input type="text" class="room-code" placeholder="Enter Room Name">
        <button class="btn play">Play Game</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert-container" data-alert-con></div>
    <div class="grid-container">
      //code 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

var room = "";
var arr = [];
var correctWord = "";
const guessGridYou = document.querySelector(".grid.you");
const guessGridOpp = document.querySelector(".grid.opponent");
const keyboard = document.querySelector(".keyboard");

const socket = io("https://wordle-server-application.glitch.me/", {headers: { "user-agent": "Google Chrome"}})
```

I tried all the past answers but they arent working.